# Supertabular paragraph environment + vertical alignment

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, supertabular

I'm trying to create supplementary materials for a paper which involves an extremely large table spanning many pages. I'm using supertabular, but I am having an alignment issue: Multi-line cells are running into the preceding \hline and I do not seem to be able to fix it. I need the rows to be bottom-aligned and (because some of this text is filled in from bibliography) extensible to unknown/referenced strings. It is also a requirement that the widths of the columns are fixed (as below). How can I stop these multi-line cells form abutting the previous \hline?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}

\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\tablefirsthead{%
Name & ID & Family & Geography & Citation \\
}
\topcaption{Language Sample}
\label{tab:languagesample}
\tablehead{%
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Name} &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{ID} &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Family} &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Geography} & 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Citation} \\}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{supertabular}{>{\raggedright}b{0.22\textwidth}b{0.1\textwidth}>{\raggedright}b{0.15\textwidth}b{0.17\textwidth}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}b{0.22\textwidth}}
\hline
Bangime & bang1363 &  & Africa & Heath and Harrigan 2018 \\ \hline
        Bench & benc1235 & Ta-Ne-Omotic & Africa & Rapold 2006 \\ \hline
\end{supertabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Note the issue with "Heath and" and "Ta-Ne"]

Answer (score 1):

As the standard solution – using the `cellspace` package doesn't seem to work with `supertabular`, I suggest to insert an invisible rule in the relevant cell:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}

\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\tablefirsthead{%
Name & ID & Family & Geography & Citation \\
}
\topcaption{Language Sample}
\label{tab:languagesample}
\tablehead{%
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Name} &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{ID} &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Family} &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Geography} &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Citation} \\}
\begin{supertabular}{>{\raggedright}b{0.22\textwidth}b{0.1\textwidth}>{\raggedright}b{0.15\textwidth}b{0.17\textwidth}%
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}b{0.22\textwidth}}
\hline
Bangime & bang1363 & & Africa & Heath and Harrigan 2018 \\ \hline
        Bench & benc1235 &\rule{0pt}{2.4ex} Ta-Ne-Omotic & Africa & Rapold 2006 \\ \hline
\end{supertabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not the most elegant thing ever but it works a treat. Thank you!